# Как с помощью @JsonProperty обозначить, что поле нужно завернуть в другой блок?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть java-объект, поле которого нужно сериализовать через Jackson в JSON не под его именем (скажем, updated), а на уровень глубже - updated.source1

```
@JsonProperty("updated.source1")
private Instant updated
```

Такое не прокатывает, данная строка читается как одно целое название атрибута, а свой сериалайзер писать ради одного поля неохота, тем более таких классов несколько.

Решение с `Map` отвергнуто как топорное

Может, кто-то в курсе, как элегантно завернуть поле? Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Comment: К сожалению, ничего нового из ответов не почерпнул :(

Answer (score 0):

В текущем объекте

```
@JsonProperty("updated")
private MyUpdated updated
```

и добавьте аналогичный объект MyUpdated

```
Class MyUpdated {
    @JsonProperty("source1")
    private String source
}
```

должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
{
updated: 
  { 
  source1: value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно кастомный десериалайзер сделать:

```
public static class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Instant> {
    @Override
    public Instant deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectNode obj = arg0.readValueAs(ObjectNode.class);
        return Instant.parse(obj.get("source1").asText());
    }

    public MyDeserializer(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Тогда поле можно так объявить:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("updated")
public Instant  updated;
```